# Using a grid reference to convert to lat/lng

Tags: coordinate-system, convert

I have a set of coordinates of the form 35KNLXXXXXX where the Xs are numbers e.g. 35KNL192274 and are in relation to Binga SE-35-7 Edition 3 and of the scale 1: 250 000.

I found the relevant map here but I don't understand how to convert my coordinates to latitude/longitude pairs.

https://esdac.jrc.ec.europa.eu/images/Eudasm/Africa/images/maps/download/PDF/afr_zw3002_4to.pdf

Any pointers?

Comment: Please add an example of your coordinates, preferably with known location. But generally, it's stated on the map that it's transverse Mercator projection, based on Clarke 1880 spheroid, so it could be EPSG:20934 or EPSG:20935.

Comment: I added an example but I don't have a known coordinate unfortunately, but it is somewhere in Zimbabwe

Comment: do you know which country it should be in?

Comment: yes, it should be in Zimbabwe

Comment: 35K refers to a grid cell in the UTM Grid zones of the world, see https://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm. NL192274 refer to a cell of subdivision of 35K. I'm not familiar with it, but I'm sure somebody will now the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To decipher your coordinates, starting point is `35K`, which denotes grid cell in UTM grid zones (see https://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm). Since projection is UTM, based on Clarke 1880 ellipsoid, CRS for map is `EPSG:20935` (see https://epsg.io/20935).

If you look at the map, coordinates of bottom left corner are `[27, -18]`. Using epsg.io site (see https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=20935&x=27.0000000&y=-18.0000000), you can get projected coordinates of the bottom left corner: `[500030, 8010110]`.

Next step is to decipher `NL192274` part of the coordinates. If you look at the bottom right of the map, you'll notice following instructions:

[image]

From this you can decipher (with some trying and testing):

- `NL` tells that reference point is lower left corner of the map;
- first three numbers denote longitude offset (left to right), second three numbers denote latitude offset (bottom up);
- in offset value from 0, first number denotes tens of kilometers, second number denotes kilometers and third number denotes tenths of kilometers;
- since horizontal numbering of offsets starts with 0, 192 means 19200 meters offset from bottom left corner X coordinate `500030`;
- since vertical numbering of offsets start with 1, 274 means 17400 meters from bottom left corner Y coordinate `8010110`.

This means that `35KNL192274` coordinate is `[519230, 8027510]` in `EPSG:20935` CRS (see https://epsg.io/map#srs=20935&x=519230&y=8027510&z=14&layer=streets). This is `[27.1811983, -17.8426445]` in `EPSG:4326` CRS (see https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=20935&t_srs=4326&x=519230.0000000&y=8027510.0000000).

For reference see [Military Grid Reference System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Grid_Reference_System)

Comment: Great answer, thank you. One question, You say that the left corner starts at 500030, why not 50000? Similarly, why not 8010000 instead of 8010110 for the vertical axis?

Comment: See https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=20935&x=27.0000000&y=-18.0000000

Answer (score 2):

I think I worked it out. Using 35KNL192274 as an example:

35K - As @tomazicM says, it refers to the UTM square.
NL - The map covers a few squares including, NL, NM, PM, and PL. These are shown at the bottom right of the map. NL covers the largest part of the map. Reading the green grid lines, the X-axis ranges from 50 - 66. NL is bounded by 50 and 60. The Y-axis ranges from 801 to 812. NL is bounded by 801 and 810.
192 - Looking at the vertical gridlines, we drop the leading 5 from the number then look for 192, i.e between 51 and 52.
274 - Similarly, we drop the 80 and 81 from the horizontal lines and look for 274, i.e 80274

If I'm right, then this seems like an entirely manual process with a lot of room for error and low granularity.